# Aligning stresses from one element to another from FEM

Tags: finite-element-method

I have a Finite Element Model (FEM) and from this model I want to transform the stresses of one element such that they align to another element's axis.

Element A:

- Centroid: [7195, 5151, 479]
- Direction: [0.921, 0.374, 0.106, 0.370, -0.927, 0.047, 0.116, -0.004, -0.993]
- Stresses: XX = 373.17, YY = -49.00, XY = 45.92

Element B:

- Centroid: [7279, 5185, 492]
- Direction: [0.928, 0.357, 0.096, -0.354, 0.993, -0.046, -0.106, 0.008, 0.994]
- Stresses: XX = 278.64, YY = 13.62, XY = -10.84

These two elements are apart of the same panel from the model, however they are not aligned equally. How would I go about transforming Element A so that it is aligned with Element B? Or another way of asking the question is, how do I treat the global axis of the system as the local axis of Element B?

The final stress values I should expect for Element A are:

- XX = 374.6
- YY = -50.5
- XY = -38.4

Comment: Are you using a particular FEA software? Any decent one should have capability of showing results in defined coordinate systems. Aligning elements coordinate systems may also be possible. What kind of elements are we talking about here?